# Vector or Tensor operator

Tags: matrices

Is there any operator that works like this:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1\\a_2\\a_3
\end{bmatrix}
\times
\begin{bmatrix}
b_1\\b_2\\b_3
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1b_1\\a_2b_2\\a_3b_3
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, indeed there is. The [Hadamard Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_%28matrices%29).